# Vim: delete empty lines within a visual selected area

Tags: vim

In ex-mode I can use `:g/^$/d` for the whole file. How to do it for a visual selected part of the file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Select text visually, press <kbd>:</kbd> to enter command mode, and use the same command or use the `'<` and `'>` markers. E.g. `:'<,'><your command here>`.

For your particular use case, the final command would be:

```
:'<,'>g/^$/d
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! If it ever where as easy ;)